# How to produce 1 row output on join case SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in an SQL Server database.

EMP table...

```
ID NAME A
-- ---- -
01 Tony Y
02 Fred N
```

and a group membership table (GRP)...

```
ID GRP    START    FINISH   KEYSK
-- ------ -------- -------- -----
01   GRP1 01/01/15 31/01/15 00001
01   GRP2 01/02/15 28/02/15 00002
01   GRP3 01/03/15 30/04/15 00003
01   GRP2 01/15/15 31/12/99 00004
01   GRPA 01/01/15 28/02/15 00005
01   GRPB 01/03/15 31/03/15 00006
01   GRPC 01/14/15 30/04/15 00007
01   GRPB 01/15/15 31/12/99 00008
02  GRPII 01/01/15 28/02/15 00005
02 GRPIII 01/03/15 31/03/15 00006
02  GRPIV 01/14/15 30/04/15 00007
02   GRPV 01/15/15 31/12/99 00008
```

I'm trying to construct a query to produce the following output that would select rows 00004 and 00008 from above as their start and end dates are current...

```
NAME GRP123 GRPABC GRPROMAN
---- ------ ------ --------
Tony   GRP2   GRPB      N/A
```

However my query returns the following...

```
NAME GRP123 GRPABC GRPROMAN
---- ------ ------ --------
Tony   GRP2    N/A      N/A
Tony    N/A   GRPB      N/A
```

Here is my attempted query, which I may have over complicated things...

```
    select NAME, 
           "GRP123" = case 
                          when GRP123.GRP='GRP1' then 'GRP1' 
                          when GRP123.GRP='GRP2' then 'GRP2' 
                          when GRP123.GRP='GRP3' then 'GRP3' 
                          else 'N/A' end,
           "GRPABC" = case 
                          when GRPABC.GRP='GRP1' then 'GRP1' 
                          when GRPABC.GRP='GRP2' then 'GRP2' 
                          when GRPABC.GRP='GRP3' then 'GRP3' 
                          else 'N/A' end,
           "GRPROMAN" = case 
                          when GRPROMAN.GRP='GRPI' then 'GRPI' 
                          when GRPROMAN.GRP='GRPII' then 'GRPII' 
                          when GRPROMAN.GRP='GRPIII' then 'GRPIII' 
                          when GRPROMAN.GRP='GRPIV' then 'GRPIV' 
                          when GRPROMAN.GRP='GRPV' then 'GRPV' 
                          when GRPROMAN.GRP='GRPVI' then 'GRPVI' 
                          else 'N/A' end,
      from EMP
full outer join GRP as GRP123 on EMP.ID = GRP123.ID and GRP123.GRP in ('GRP1', 'GRP2', 'GRP3')
full outer join GRP as GRPABC on EMP.ID = GRPABC.ID and GRPABC.GRP in ('GRPA', 'GRPB', 'GRPC')
full outer join GRP as GRPROMAN on EMP.ID = GRPROMAN.ID and GRPROMAN.GRP in ('GRPI', 'GRPII', 'GRPIII', 'GRPIV', 'GRPV', 'GRPVI')
     where EMP.A = 'T'
  order by EMP.NAME
;
```

Any help / guidance would be much appreciated.

An optional improvement output could be...

```
NAME GRP123 GRP123START GRPABC GRPABCSTART GRPROMAN GRPROMANSTART
---- ------ ----------- ------ ----------- -------- -------------
Tony   GRP2    01/15/15   GRPB    01/15/15      N/A           N/A
```

Thanks, AjN3806

Comment: what do you mean with start and end dates are current?

Comment: How do you define what entry should be used? Is it the latest startdate, latest enddate, id, something else entirely?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use subquery in each coumn like below:

```
SELECT
    NAME,
    GRP123 = ISNULL((
        SELECT TOP 1
            GRP
        FROM 
            GRP g
        WHERE 
            GRP IN (
                'GRP1', 'GRP2', 'GRP3')
            AND g.KEYSK IN ('00004', '00008')
            AND e.ID = g.ID 
    ), 'N/A'),
    GRPABC = ISNULL((
        SELECT TOP 1
            GRP
        FROM 
            GRP g
        WHERE 
            GRP IN (
                'GRPA', 'GRPB', 'GRPC')
            AND g.KEYSK IN ('00004', '00008')
            AND e.ID = g.ID 
    ), 'N/A'),
    GRPROMAN = ISNULL((
        SELECT TOP 1
            GRP
        FROM 
            GRP g
        WHERE 
            GRP IN (
                'GRPI', 'GRPII', 'GRPIII', 'GRPIV', 'GRPV', 'GRPVI')
            AND g.KEYSK IN ('00004', '00008')
            AND e.ID = g.ID 
    ), 'N/A')
FROM
    EMP e
WHERE
    e.A = 'Y'
ORDER BY
    e.NAME
```

Comment: Thanks dee.ronin for the idea.  Works well.

Answer (score 0):

The data are obviously wrong, as 01/15/15 and 31/12/99 can hardly be both dates in the same format. If dates were stored as dates, this could never happen. I at least hope that user ID is not char(2). While You mention 00004 and 00008 rows, I doubt You want to hard code them into the query. What you probably want is query user status to a date. With date stored as (incorrect) string this is challenging, but with proper data type it is not a problem:

```
declare @EMP table(ID smallint, NAME nvarchar(50), A char(1));
insert into @EMP values
(01, 'Tony', 'Y'), 
(02, 'Fred','N');

declare @GRP table(ID smallint, GRP varchar(50), START date, FINISH date, KEYSK int);
insert into @GRP values
(01,   'GRP1', '2015/01/01', '2015/01/31', 00001),
(01,   'GRP2', '2015/02/01', '2015/02/28', 00002),
(01,   'GRP3', '2015/03/01', '2015/04/30', 00003),
(01,   'GRP2', '2015/05/01', '2099/12/31', 00004),
(01,   'GRPA', '2015/01/01', '2015/02/28', 00005),
(01,   'GRPB', '2015/03/01', '2015/03/31', 00006),
(01,   'GRPC', '2015/04/01', '2015/04/30', 00007),
(01,   'GRPB', '2015/05/01', '2099/12/31', 00008),
(02,  'GRPII', '2015/01/01', '2015/02/28', 00005),
(02, 'GRPIII', '2015/03/01', '2015/03/31', 00006),
(02,  'GRPIV', '2015/04/01', '2015/04/30', 00007),
(02,   'GRPV', '2015/05/01', '2099/12/31', 00008);

declare @DATE date;
set @DATE = GETDATE();

-- Output with N/A
    --isnull(GRP123.GRP, 'N/A') as 'GRP123',
    --isnull(CONVERT(varchar(50), GRP123.START), 'N/A') as 'GRP123START',
    --isnull(GRPABC.GRP, 'N/A') as 'GRPABC',
    --isnull(CONVERT(varchar(50), GRPABC.START), 'N/A') as 'GRPABCSTART',
    --isnull(GRPROMAN.GRP, 'N/A') as 'GRPROMAN',
    --isnull(CONVERT(varchar(50), GRPROMAN.START), 'N/A') as 'GRPROMANSTART'

select NAME, 
    GRP123.GRP as 'GRP123',
    GRP123.START as 'GRP123START',
    GRPABC.GRP as 'GRPABC',
    GRPABC.START as 'GRPABCSTART',
    GRPROMAN.GRP as 'GRPROMAN',
    GRPROMAN.START as 'GRPROMANSTART'

from @EMP E

left join @GRP as GRP123 on E.ID = GRP123.ID 
and GRP123.GRP in ('GRP1', 'GRP2', 'GRP3') 
and GRP123.START <= @DATE and @DATE <= GRP123.FINISH

left join @GRP as GRPABC on E.ID = GRPABC.ID 
and GRPABC.GRP in ('GRPA', 'GRPB', 'GRPC') 
and GRPABC.START <= @DATE and @DATE <= GRPABC.FINISH

left join @GRP as GRPROMAN on E.ID = GRPROMAN.ID 
and GRPROMAN.GRP in ('GRPI', 'GRPII', 'GRPIII', 'GRPIV', 'GRPV', 'GRPVI') 
and GRPROMAN.START <= @DATE and @DATE <= GRPROMAN.FINISH

where E.A = 'Y'
order by E.NAME
```

I commented out version with those N/A as I think that the way NULL is displayed should be handled in application. But You can use it if You like.

Answer (score 0):

There are various **mistakes in the question**, so my answer moves by steps and ipotheses <del>and is **incomplete**. I hope however it could be a valid starting point to write the targeted query</del>.

First of all there's surely a typo in the case for `"GRPABC"`, misaligned from the criteria of the second full outer join (that producing results aliased with `GRPABC`), with the result of falling always in the `"N/A"` case.
I'm assuming the criteria on join is correct and so, at first, the `"GRPABC"` colum might be:

```
      "GRPABC" = case 
                      when GRPABC.GRP='GRPA' then 'GRPA' 
                      when GRPABC.GRP='GRPB' then 'GRPB' 
                      when GRPABC.GRP='GRPC' then 'GRPC' 
                      else 'N/A' end,
```

Also the *where clause* seems wrong: assuming `EMP.NAME = 'Y'` (`'T'`?!), it doesn't deal however about your question regarding dates issues (current?). 
And what about datetime values (1999!?)?.
But move on by steps:

1. we can correct the *case criteria*;
2. i'd move the clauses on outer join as where clauses of subqueries, considering that you produce `NULL` values joining the three *"GRP's configurations of values"* and being still able to express the `"N/A"` case.
3. we can bypass completely the *case statement* thanks to new possibilities form the second point rewriting, dealing directly with `NULL` ot `NOT NULL` values (by the mean of `coalesce`; as a track leading to this, consider that the *case statement* is only repeating 'good' values and having a default 'not good' case).

In practice you could rewrite to this:

```
select NAME, 
    coalesce(GRP123.GRP, 'N/A') as 'GRP123',
    coalesce(GRPABC.GRP, 'N/A') as 'GRPABC',
    coalesce(GRPROMAN.GRP, 'N/A') as 'GRPROMAN' 
from EMP 
    full outer join (select * from GRP WHERE GRP in ('GRP1', 'GRP2', 'GRP3')) as GRP123 on EMP.ID = GRP123.ID 
    full outer join (select * from GRP WHERE GRP in ('GRPA', 'GRPB', 'GRPC')) as GRPABC on EMP.ID = GRPABC.ID 
    full outer join (select * from GRP WHERE GRP in ('GRPI', 'GRPII', 'GRPIII', 'GRPIV', 'GRPV', 'GRPVI')) as GRPROMAN on EMP.ID = GRPROMAN.ID 
--where EMP.A = 'Y'
```

But the above query doesn't face the *'current' filter* and has a bug because can't produce a configuration with all `"N/A"` values.
So further steps are going this direction, changing filter and join types, and introducing a *'pivoting'* query for *all-"N/A"-values* case plus a `DISTINCT` clause.

Dealing with the *'current' filter*, you should avoid the use of a *'bad value'* like `'1999-12-31 00:00:00'` because it's a valid date. Why not use the `NULL` value?
But i'll follow your design and so the query becomes:

```
select DISTINCT NAME, 
    coalesce(GRP123.GRP, 'N/A') as 'GRP123',
    coalesce(GRPABC.GRP, 'N/A') as 'GRPABC',
    coalesce(GRPROMAN.GRP, 'N/A') as 'GRPROMAN' 
from EMP 
    inner join (select * from GRP WHERE FINISH < '2000-01-01 00:00:00') as GRP_PIVOTING on EMP.ID = GRP_PIVOTING.ID 
    left join (select * from GRP WHERE GRP in ('GRP1', 'GRP2', 'GRP3') AND FINISH < '2000-01-01 00:00:00') as GRP123 on EMP.ID = GRP123.ID 
    left join (select * from GRP WHERE GRP in ('GRPA', 'GRPB', 'GRPC') AND FINISH < '2000-01-01 00:00:00') as GRPABC on EMP.ID = GRPABC.ID 
    left join (select * from GRP WHERE GRP in ('GRPI', 'GRPII', 'GRPIII', 'GRPIV', 'GRPV', 'GRPVI') AND FINISH < '2000-01-01 00:00:00') as GRPROMAN on EMP.ID = GRPROMAN.ID
    where EMP.A = 'Y'
```

Optional output could be targeted with a quick extend using the same *colaesce logic*, after casting the `datetime` type to correctly fall back in the `'N/A'` value.

This brings to reach this final and the requested:

```
select DISTINCT NAME, 
    coalesce(GRP123.GRP, 'N/A') as 'GRP123', coalesce(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GRP123.START, 120), 'N/A') as 'GRP123START',
    coalesce(GRPABC.GRP, 'N/A') as 'GRPABC', coalesce(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GRPABC.START, 120), 'N/A') as 'GRPABCSTART',
    coalesce(GRPROMAN.GRP, 'N/A') as 'GRPROMAN', coalesce(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GRPROMAN.START, 120), 'N/A') as 'GRPROMANSTART' 
from EMP 
    inner join (select * from GRP WHERE FINISH < '2000-01-01 00:00:00') as GRP_PIVOTING on EMP.ID = GRP_PIVOTING.ID 
    left join (select * from GRP WHERE GRP in ('GRP1', 'GRP2', 'GRP3') AND FINISH < '2000-01-01 00:00:00') as GRP123 on EMP.ID = GRP123.ID 
    left join (select * from GRP WHERE GRP in ('GRPA', 'GRPB', 'GRPC') AND FINISH < '2000-01-01 00:00:00') as GRPABC on EMP.ID = GRPABC.ID 
    left join (select * from GRP WHERE GRP in ('GRPI', 'GRPII', 'GRPIII', 'GRPIV', 'GRPV', 'GRPVI') AND FINISH < '2000-01-01 00:00:00') as GRPROMAN on EMP.ID = GRPROMAN.ID
    where EMP.A = 'Y'
```

Answer (score 0):

What about a couple of scalar functions that take the ID of the EMP and get the corresponding "00004" and "00008" values?

something like:

```
CREATE FUNTION dbo.fnGRP00004 (@id int) RETURNS Varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ret varchar(30)
SELECT @ret=GRP FROM EMP
WHERE id=@id AND KEYSK='00004'
RETURN @ret
END



CREATE FUNTION dbo.fnGRP00008 (@id int) RETURNS Varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @ret varchar(30)
SELECT @ret=GRP FROM EMP
WHERE id=@id AND KEYSK='00008'
RETURN @ret
END

SELECT NAME, dbo.GRP00004(id) as GRP123, dbo.GRP00008(id) as GRPABC
FROM EMP
```

If you want to add dates, you could follow a similar path.
Maybe not the best in terms of performance, the functions above will be called for each row in the EMP table, if there are many rows it could be heavy.

Additional info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191320.aspx